# Filtering all rows with NaT in a column in Dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like this:

```
    a b           c
    1 NaT         w
    2 2014-02-01  g
    3 NaT         x   

    df=df[df.b=='2014-02-01']
```

will give me

```
    a  b          c
    2 2014-02-01  g
```

I want a database of all rows with NaT in column b?

```
   df=df[df.b==None] #Doesn't work
```

I want this:

```
    a b           c
    1 NaT         w
    3 NaT         x
```

Comment: umm, df[df.b == pd.NaT]?

Comment: @acushner: `pd.NaT != pd.NaT`, though, like `nan != nan`.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

`isnull` and `notnull` work with `NaT` so you can handle them much the same way you handle `NaNs`:

```
>>> df

   a          b  c
0  1        NaT  w
1  2 2014-02-01  g
2  3        NaT  x

>>> df.dtypes

a             int64
b    datetime64[ns]
c            object
```

just use `isnull` to select:

```
df[df.b.isnull()]

   a   b  c
0  1 NaT  w
2  3 NaT  x
```

Comment: Maybe it's better for the recent versions of pandas to use **.loc** method for slicing the DataFrames, something like this:  `df.loc[df.b.isnull()]`

Answer (score 12):

Using your example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3], 
                   "b":[pd.NaT, pd.to_datetime("2014-02-01"), pd.NaT], 
                   "c":["w", "g", "x"]})
```

Until v0.17 this didn't use to work:

```
df.query('b != b')
```

and you had to do:

```
df.query('b == "NaT"') # yes, surprisingly, this works!
```

Since v0.17 though, both methods work, although I would only recommend the first one.

Answer (score 12):

For those interested, in my case I wanted to drop the NaT contained in the DateTimeIndex of a dataframe. I could not directly use the notnull construction as suggested by Karl D. You first have to create a temporary column out of the index, then apply the mask, and then delete the temporary column again.

```
df["TMP"] = df.index.values                # index is a DateTimeIndex
df = df[df.TMP.notnull()]                  # remove all NaT values
df.drop(["TMP"], axis=1, inplace=True)     # delete TMP again
```

Comment: At least with current pandas 1.33 that works just fine to filter out NaT rows of the index:

`df = df.loc[~df.index.isnull()]`

Answer (score 10):

I feel that the comment by @DSM is worth a answer on its own, because this answers the fundamental question.

The misunderstanding comes from the assumption that `pd.NaT` acts like `None`. However, while `None == None` returns `True`, `pd.NaT == pd.NaT` returns `False`. Pandas `NaT` behaves like a floating-point `NaN`, which is not equal to itself.

As the previous answer explain, you should use

```
df[df.b.isnull()] # or notnull(), respectively
```