# How to find empty datatime in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe which has a column `date_closed` of type `datetime64[ns]`. When I find the unique values there are some NaT there. How can I only filter the rows whose date_closed in not NaT

```
df['date_closes'].unique()
```

btw, what does NaT means? is it Null? 
When I value_counts() , the NaT's does not appear! Why?

```
df['date_closed'].value_counts()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering all rows with NaT in a column in Dataframe python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747451/filtering-all-rows-with-nat-in-a-column-in-dataframe-python)

Comment: NaT is a null value recognized by pandas, so it returns `True` for functions like `df.date_closed.isnull()`

Answer (score 2):

For `datetime64[ns]` types, NaT represents `missing` values. This is a pseudo-native sentinel value that can be represented by numpy in a singular dtype (datetime64[ns]). pandas objects provide intercompatibility between NaT and NaN.

You can read more about handling missing data here :  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

For filtering, you can use `notnull` method.

```
df['date_closed'] = df[df.date_closed.notnull()]
```

Comment: This works but if I write it as a lambda function, it says Timestamp object has no attribute notnull. Why?

Comment: Can you post your lambda function ?

Answer (score 0):

Th null value `NaT` means not a time just like `NaN` means not a number.

Use `dropna`

```
df.dropna(subset=[“date_closed”])
```