# i am getting "builtins.KeyError: 'DATE'" error while trying to use Datetime for one of my columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, resampling

while i am trying to resample my dataframe in python using pandas. i am getting builtins.KerError: 'Date' when i am trying to split my index in the first dataframe.

---

I am very new to development and any answer with a reason why it was getting generated would be of lot of help.

---

this is how my dataframe looks like with multiple entries for each second, on which i wanted to do ohlc resampling.

```
                 Time   Token     LTP   Volume
0 2019-01-18 15:29:59  779521  294.95  9074206
0 2019-01-18 15:29:59  779521  294.95  9074206
0 2019-01-18 15:29:59  779521  294.95  9074206
0 2019-01-18 15:40:02  779521  294.95  9074723
0 2019-01-18 15:40:02  779521  294.95  9074723
0 2019-01-18 15:40:03  779521  294.95  9074725
0 2019-01-18 15:40:03  779521  294.95  9074725
0 2019-01-18 15:40:03  779521  294.95  9074725
0 2019-01-18 15:40:05  779521  294.95  9074736
0 2019-01-18 15:40:05  779521  294.95  9074736
0 2019-01-18 15:40:05  779521  294.95  9074736
0 2019-01-18 15:40:11  779521  294.95  9074986
0 2019-01-18 15:40:11  779521  294.95  9074986
0 2019-01-18 15:40:11  779521  294.95  9074986
0 2019-01-18 15:40:13  779521  294.95  9075386
0 2019-01-18 15:40:13  779521  294.95  9075386
0 2019-01-18 15:40:25  779521  294.95  9075586
0 2019-01-18 15:40:25  779521  294.95  9075586
0 2019-01-18 15:40:25  779521  294.95  9075586
0 2019-01-18 15:40:25  779521  294.95  9075586
0 2019-01-18 15:40:32  779521  294.95  9075686
0 2019-01-18 15:40:32  779521  294.95  9075686
0 2019-01-18 15:40:32  779521  294.95  9075686
0 2019-01-18 15:40:40  779521  294.95  9075687
0 2019-01-18 15:40:40  779521  294.95  9075787
0 2019-01-18 15:40:40  779521  294.95  9075787
0 2019-01-18 15:40:40  779521  294.95  9075787
0 2019-01-18 15:40:40  779521  294.95  9075787
```

---

My Code

```
df_cols = ["Time", "Token", "LTP", "Volume"]

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data=[],columns=df_cols)

timeframe = '1min'

def on_ticks(ws, ticks): #retrive continius ticks in JSON format
    global data_frame, df_cols

    data = dict()

    for tick in ticks:
        Time = tick['last_trade_time']
        Token = tick['instrument_token']
        LTP = tick['last_price']
        Volume = tick['volume']

        data = [Time, Token, LTP, Volume]

    tick_df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=df_cols)
    data_frame = data_frame.append(tick_df)

    data_frame['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data_frame['DATE'] + ' ' + data_frame['TIME'])
    data_frame.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
```

i am getting the following error builtins.KerError: 'Date'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling the column "Date" from you dataframe but the dataframe does not have a column with the name.

```
data_frame['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data_frame['DATE'] + ' ' + data_frame['TIME'])
```

Comment: Thanks, your pointing out worked. i commented out the Date code. But now i am seeing a new issue..

The data from tick_df which is getting appended into the final data frame. The date column is getting converted to NaT. Can you please solve this as well. would be of much help.

The data frame after commenting out the line you mentioned.

NaT                  293.00  779521  9189017
NaT                  293.00  779521  9189017
2019-01-21 15:11:51  292.85  779521  9202831

Comment: Nat is used to represent missing datetime values.  General info  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html here is a thread on how to filter Nats out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747451/filtering-all-rows-with-nat-in-a-column-in-dataframe-python